# Spring Boot: custom Validator doesn't resolve validation error messages

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a custom class that implements the `org.springframework.validation.Validator` interface, and I'm injecting it into a class annotated with `@Service`. In my Spring Boot 3.0.1 application, I'm using this custom validator with the following code:

```
validator.validate(request, new BeanPropertyBindingResult(request, "RequestClass"));
```

It's worth noting that I'm not using the `@Valid` annotation for validation.

My issue is that when I use `errors.rejectValue("fieldName", "validation.error.key")` in my custom validator, it doesn't resolve the value for the specified error key. However, when I inject an appropriate `MessageSource`, the key works perfectly.

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to make my custom validator resolve error messages without the need for an injected `MessageSource`.